# What is calldata offset for dynamic calldata arrays?

Tags: solidity, arrays, assembly, calldata, data-types

The [Solidity docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.18/assembly.html) say this about dynamic calldata arrays:

> For dynamic calldata arrays, you can access their calldata offset (in bytes) and length (number of elements) using `x.offset` and `x.length`

But they don't offer any example.

What does an "offset" mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`offset` is the position in the calldata where the actual data of the array starts, i.e. where the first array element is located. Let's take an example:

```
contract Foo {
    function getOffset(uint256[] calldata arr) external pure returns (uint256 offset) {
        assembly {
            offset := arr.offset
        }
    }
}
```

Passing `[1,2,3]` as an input to this function would return 68:

[image: Call to Foo.getOffset]

Now, let's define another parameter in the function, before `arr`:

```
function getOffset (uint256 param, uint256[] calldata arr) external pure returns (uint256 offset) {
    assembly {
        offset := arr.offset
    }
}
```

Passing `0,[1,2,3]` as an input would now return 100 instead of 68, because there is another EVM word that sits before `arr`, and EVM words are 32 byte long:

[image: Second call to Foo.getOffset]

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have this function:

```
contract Foo {
    function getOffset(uint256[] calldata arr) external pure returns (uint256 offset) {
        assembly {
            offset := arr.offset
        }
    }
}
```

Passing `[1, 2, 3]` as an input to this function would return **68**.
but how it calculated 68?

Based on the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html#argument-encoding) we can find encoded argument, which for this input and function argument it will be:

```
0x1fe457d7                                                         - function signature
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 - offset of [1,2,3]
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 - count for [1,2,3]
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 - encoding of 1
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002 - encoding of 2
  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003 - encoding of 3
```

If you count number of bytes from the `function signature` line (4 bytes)  to the beginning of the line `encoding of 1` where the actual data of the array starts, you will find out there are **68** bytes.